# When do they prepare screenplay for sequels, after casting or before casting?

Tags: production, casting, sequels

Magic Mike XXL is a sequel for Magic Mike. However in the sequel the Dallas role is not there. Did they remove the role because Matthew McConaughey was busy with another movie or was it developed not to include the role.

When do they prepare screenplay for sequels, after casting or before casting?

Comment: How do you cast a movie (or tv-show or play) before you know what roles are required?

Comment: I think it depends.  For a major roles that they would often want to carry into the sequel, they probably find out whether the actor is available or not before deciding whether to even make the sequel.  Sometimes they would have an outline for a script of a sequel in advance, sometimes not, especially for surprise hit movies

Comment: For a major roles that they would often want to carry into the sequel they would generally sign the *significant actor* to a multi-picture deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenplays must be ready, or mostly complete, before casting can be done. Without a screenplay or conceptual basis for the characters, how would you know who to cast? That the actor/actress fits what you need in terms of looks, attitude, etc.

But screenplays and scripts are not a single static event. They get rewritten and changed as an ongoing process all the way up to primary shooting. And even then can still be changed and secondary re-shooting takes place.

There is no single answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I would think screenplays are made after the story is written. Translating from paper to what people would say on film. Casting, in relation to the question-would be discussed during the screenplay revisions, to ensure that all parts are covered, or if another actor is added and needs lines or a story. Really, it's not before or after, more like during.

Comment: The point of this question, however, is when the casting is technically already completed, as in the case of a sequel. Writing a script and then finding out that your star is unwilling to appear in the sequel is problematic and you have to rewrite... or even scrap the project entirely.